Building houses in the Kingdom of heaven
It says in the Bible that:

They will build houses and dwell in them;
they will plant vineyards and eat their fruit.
No longer will they build houses and others live in them,
or plant and others eat.
(Isaiah 65:21-22, NIV)

Does this mean that heaven is literally just just going to be Eden all over again?

"It says that we will build houses with our own hands in the kingdom" - where is that said?

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. Please give us the Bible books, chapter and verses you refer to when you say "It says that..." otherwise we can't answer your question. Please also take our Tour to understand what we look for in questions: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Heaven is no where described so we do not know.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Snowman. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

The short answer is yes, but this should be seen positively, not negatively.
The overall story of the Bible is that "in the beginning God created the heavens and the earth." Tragically that creation was greatly marred by human sin, but God has always been at work bringing about the complete healing of his creation. That work is centred on the life, death and resurrection of Jesus, and the Christian hope is that one day all things will be made new in Christ.
Now throughout the Bible that hope is expressed in many ways, and Isaiah 65 is certainly one of those ways. The context is Isaiah's great vision of the last days:

See, I will create
new heavens and a new earth.
The former things will not be remembered,
nor will they come to mind.
But be glad and rejoice forever
in what I will create.
(Isaiah 65:18-19 NIV)

Isaiah then continues to expand on that dream and vision in the language of OT Israel. Jerusalem will flourish. Everyone will live a long and productive life. Grand houses will be built, and vineyards will bring great harvests. In all these ways God will bring total blessing to his people and his creation.
It's worth noting that "a new heaven and earth" is an intentional reference back to Genesis 1 and the original creation story. Isaiah is looking forward to what God will do, but he understands God's work as a restoration to the time where "God saw everything he had created, and behold it was very good." (Genesis 1:31)
And finally, note also that the word pictures which Isaiah paints are very physical, even "literal" as the OP suggests. But this is exactly what we should expect. We are creatures of time and space, and all our descriptions of the spiritual world must use the language of creation as we experience it. Even the word "heaven" is an example of that process. The heavens are a physical reality that we see when we look up into the sky. But we also use that word to describe something impossible, namely the place where God (who is beyond time and space) lives.
So when we read passages like Isaiah 65, the most important thing is to use our imaginations and let God reveal to us hints of something that will be far beyond our wildest imaginings.
